# Symfony 3 - ManyToMany problem with my entities

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many

I have a weird problem on Symfony 3.4

I clarify the situation: I have two entities:

**UserType** and **Package**.
The goal is to offer packages to my users based on their user type (users will only see the packages corresponding to their user type).

A package can belong to more than one user type, and a user type can have multiple packages.

So I have a relation ManyToMany.

**TypeUser.php**

```
namespace Site\PagesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TypeUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="type_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Site\PagesBundle\Repository\TypeUserRepository")
 */
class TypeUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="typeUtilisateur", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $typeUtilisateur;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set typeUtilisateur
     *
     * @param string $typeUtilisateur
     *
     * @return TypeUser
     */
    public function setTypeUtilisateur($typeUtilisateur)
    {
        $this->typeUtilisateur = $typeUtilisateur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get typeUtilisateur
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTypeUtilisateur()
    {
        return $this->typeUtilisateur;
    }
}
```

**Paquet.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Site\PagesBundle\Entity;
//use
/**
 * Paquet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="paquet")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Site\PagesBundle\Repository\PaquetRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Paquet
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**  
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TypeUser")  
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Packages_des_TypesUser") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */  
    private $typeUser;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->typeUser = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /** 
     * Get TypeUser 
     * 
     * @return Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser 
     */ 
    public function getTypeUser() 
    { 
        return $this->typeUser; 
    }
    public function deleteTypeFromTypesUser(TypeUser $type)
    {
        $this->typeUser->removeElement($type);
    }
    /**
     * Set typeUser
     *
     * @param Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser $typeUser
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setTypeUser(Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser $typeUser)
    {
        $this->typeUser = $typeUser;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

So, when I add a package, I can select some TypeUser :

[image]

And when I manage packages :

[image]

Now, if I want to modify a package by adding a user type, there will be a problem:

I've my package : Let's to add a new TypeUser by clicking on "Modifier"

[image]

Let's check "DAFPIC" :

[image]

Ok, I've the package which is on DAFPIC too, now, with a new line on my association on the database :

[image]
[image]

But now, if I click on "Supprimer" from DAFPIC new package, if I dump the TypeUser of this package, I get the first typeUser :

[image]

So, I don't understand what's wrong... Can someone help me please ?

EDIT:

When I click on the delete button :

```
/**
     * Suppression d'un package | Suppression d'un type d'utilisateur attribué à un package
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/{type}/delete", name="paquets_delete")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id, $type)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $unPaquet = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Paquet')->find($id); //Récupération du package
        $leType = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:TypeUser')->findOneByTypeUtilisateur($type);
        dump($leType);

        $em->remove($unPaquet);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('paquets_index'); // Actualisation de la page
}
```

EDIT: Take a look on my schema :

[image]

Comment: The query, that fetches the TypeUser, does not matter, as you will always remove the Paquet you fetch before anyway. If you just want to remove the package, then you can ignore the type. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are deleting the package, not the associated UserTypePaquet between Paquet and UserType.

```
USER_TYPE <== USER_TYPE_PAQUET ==> PAQUET.
                    ^^               ^^
                    ||               ||
                    ||               ||
          you should delete this     ||
                                     ||
              you are currently deleting this
```

*(and your are certainly deleting all associations with packages too)*

You have to select all packages associated to this user (by calling the collection with getPaquets()) and remove one element on it, the concerned package.

```php
    /**
     * Suppression d'un package | Suppression d'un type d'utilisateur attribué à un package
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/{type}/delete", name="paquets_delete")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id, $type)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $unPaquet = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Paquet')->find($id); //Récupération du package
        $leType = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:TypeUser')->findOneByTypeUtilisateur($type);
        dump($leType);

        //$em->remove($unPaquet); <=== DO NOT remove THE PAQUET
        $leType->getPaquets()->remove($unPaquet);// <=== Remove only the paquet associated to user
        $em->persist($leType); //Then save $leType sans le paquet associé
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('paquets_index'); // Actualisation de la page
    }
```

This solution is the first step to resolv your problem. Now you have to delete the use the PaquetDDLCas entities. You have two solutions: The first one (the better) is too update your database schema to add a "on delete cascade" constraint between PaquetDDLCas on the foreign key linking PaquetDDLCas to PackageTypeUser.

```sql
ALTER TABLE PaquetDDLCas ADD CONSTRAINT FK_xxxx FOREIGN KEY (paquet_id, type_user_id) REFERENCES Package_typeuser (paquet_id, type_user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE')
```

*If you correctly link PaquetDDLCas to PaquetTypeUser (and removes your two links, one on Paquet, the other one on PaquetTypeUser) and check orphan doctrine attribute to "yes", this code will be generated by doctrine.*

The second method consist to do it manually and call your `PaquetDDLCasRepository` and creating a new function which delete all data.

```php
public function deleteByPaquetAndTypeUser($paquet,$user)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    $qb->delete()
       ->where('p.user = :user')
       ->andWhere('p.paquet = :paquet')
       ->setParameter('user', $user)
       ->setParameter('paquet', $paquet)
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();
}
```

But this method is not a good practice.

Comment: The general idea sounds right, but the code is probably wrong. You do not need to perst `$leType`. Instead you should call `$em->flush();`

Comment: Correct, I added flush. But are you sure that persist is not needed? I will test it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will test that ! :)

Comment: The main problem, which I may have forgotten to mention, is that I have a UserDDL entity that contains the user_id, and the package_id, and the download date. My final goal when I delete a package related to a user type is to be able to delete the rows of the UserDDL entity that contain the selected package for the selected user type

Comment: I think that I'll use the second solution.But I haven't "typeUser" attribute on PaquetDDLCas, and I'm a beginner in Symfony, I don't know how can I make a join column in DQL (with UserCas on typeUser ? )

Comment: My bad, I updated typeUser by user in Repository code.

Comment: Is not "->where('p.user = :typeUser')" rather ->where('p.TypeUser = :typeUser') ?
Because I don't have a TypeUser attribute on PaquetDDLCas